# How do I enable GitHub-hosted runners for a GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I created a workflow for [my Python repo](https://github.com/DidierMalenfant/toybox.py) as follows:

```yaml
name: Python package

on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install flake8 pytest semver
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings.
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --ignore=E501 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
```

Unfortunately, the action never runs and times out with the error:

```
This request was automatically failed because there were no enabled runners online to process the request for more than 1 days.
```

Did I do something silly in the configuration file?

I'm currently on a free GitHub account. Are GitHub-hosted runners available on free accounts? If so how do I enable one of those?

Comment: First time I'm seeing this. Did you maybe reach the runner limit allowed to free account each month? (you can check this on your account settings)

Comment: Yeah, this was literally the first action I ever ran... I did find the issue though. User error. I'll post the reply below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out

```
runs-on: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
```

doesn't run the action on each platforms. Instead it tries to find a runner that satisfies both conditions, i.e. running on `ubuntu-latest` and  `macos-latest` which is, of course, never found.

The way to so what I originally intended is to, instead, do a two-dimensional matrix for os and python-version.